# Custom View not rendering

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

This is my first attempt at creating custom Views in Android. However, I seem to have missed something and don't know how to debug the issue. I have written a custom View to draw Bars Chart in Android with their values below the bars. My onDraw method in code is as follows:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    if (mBars == null) {
        return
    }
    canvas.save()
    val rectBaseLine = measuredHeight * FRACTIONAL_MAX_BAR_HEIGHT + convertDpToPixel(TOP_MARGIN_FOR_BAR, context);
    canvas.translate(0f, rectBaseLine.toFloat())

    mBars.forEach {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(it.mRect,
                BAR_CORNER_RADIUS, BAR_CORNER_RADIUS,
                mapToPaints.getValue(it.paintType))

        var textWidth = textPaint.measureText(it.num.toString())

        canvas.drawText(it.num.toString(),
                it.mRect.left + (it.mRect.right - it.mRect.left) / 2 - textWidth / 2,
                convertSpToPixel(TEXT_SIZE, context) + convertDpToPixel(DISTANCE_BW_TEXT_N_BAR, context),
                mapToTextPaints.getValue(it.paintType))
    }

    canvas.restore()
}

fun prepareBarsArr(arr: IntArray) {
    val max = arr.max();
    val viewHeight = measuredHeight
    val rectHeight = measuredHeight * FRACTIONAL_MAX_BAR_HEIGHT /*- ( convertSpToPixel(TEXT_SIZE, context) +  convertDpToPixel(DISTANCE_BW_TEXT_N_BAR, context))*/;
    val width = measuredWidth
    widthPerBar = (width - INTER_BAR_GAP * (arr.size - 1)) / arr.size

    var currentX = -widthPerBar - INTER_BAR_GAP
    mBars = Array<BarDetails>(arr.size, {
        val desiredHeight = arr[it] * rectHeight / max!!
        currentX += widthPerBar + INTER_BAR_GAP
        val mRect = RectF(currentX.toFloat(), 0f, (currentX + widthPerBar).toFloat(), (-desiredHeight).toFloat());
        BarDetails(mRect, arr[it], STATEPAINTS.NORMAL)
    });


    invalidate()
}
```

mBars stores Bar related informations eg: the Rect object, numeric value (which helps determine height of the bar), paint to use etc.

The problem is this code runs perfectly on Emulator but on my Device (Using Lenovo Zuk Z2 Plus), it doesn't draw bars. I checked a few posts and tried different combinations with hardwareAccelerated ="true/false" 
 and drawRoundRect/drawRect etc. There was only 1 combination where the bars showed up on my Device that was when hardwareAccelerated was false and I was using drawRect. However, when I use RoundedRect the bars don't show up. Don't know if this is a device specific issue as I have only 1 device to test on. Either ways, some points on how to debug this would be helpful.

Comment: Please include the full code. Are you calling `invalidate()` after changing your `mBars`? Are you properly measuring/layouting, or do you let the parent `View` handle it? etc

Comment: invalidate is called after mBars Array is prepared. I have included the code for that. However, I don't think this could be related to wrong invalidate calls as its working on emulator correctly. I also tested it by creating a button, which explicitly calls invalidate on the custom view when pressed. There is no measuring/layouting as device width is used and fixed height is given to custom view in xml itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by rewriting the logic to create bars. In the code in question, I used to translate the canvas and then draw the bars/Rect from Bottom to Top. I just changed the calculations to create Rect with Top at the top of the Rect and Bottom at the rectHeight. The following are the modified code and this renders even the RoundedRect. I have android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in my Manifest file. Also, earlier I was doing save and restore which is not required now as the translation of canvas is not done.

```
fun prepareBarsArr(arr: IntArray) {
    val max = arr.max();
    val viewHeight = measuredHeight
    val rectHeight = measuredHeight * FRACTIONAL_MAX_BAR_HEIGHT /*- ( convertSpToPixel(TEXT_SIZE, context) +  convertDpToPixel(DISTANCE_BW_TEXT_N_BAR, context))*/;
    val width = measuredWidth
    widthPerBar = (width - INTER_BAR_GAP * (arr.size + 1)) / arr.size

    var currentX = INTER_BAR_GAP
    mBars = Array<BarDetails>(arr.size, {
        val desiredHeight = arr[it] * rectHeight / max!!
        val mRect = RectF(currentX.toFloat(),
                rectHeight - desiredHeight,
                (currentX + widthPerBar).toFloat(),
                (rectHeight).toFloat()
        );
        currentX += widthPerBar + INTER_BAR_GAP
        BarDetails(mRect, arr[it], STATEPAINTS.NORMAL)
    });


    invalidate()
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    if (mBars == null) {
        return
    }

    /*val rectBaseLine = measuredHeight * FRACTIONAL_MAX_BAR_HEIGHT + convertDpToPixel(TOP_MARGIN_FOR_BAR, context);*/ /*- ( convertSpToPixel(TEXT_SIZE, context) +  convertDpToPixel(DISTANCE_BW_TEXT_N_BAR, context))*/;
    /*canvas.translate(0f, rectBaseLine.toFloat())*/

    mBars.forEach {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(it.mRect,
                BAR_CORNER_RADIUS, BAR_CORNER_RADIUS,
                mapToPaints.getValue(it.paintType))

        var textWidth = textPaint.measureText(it.num.toString())

        canvas.drawText(it.num.toString(),
                it.mRect.left + (it.mRect.right - it.mRect.left) / 2 - textWidth / 2,
                convertSpToPixel(TEXT_SIZE, context) + convertDpToPixel(DISTANCE_BW_TEXT_N_BAR, context) + it.mRect.bottom,
                mapToTextPaints.getValue(it.paintType))
    }
}
```

If someone would like to add, I would appreciate reasoning behind this. Was I doing something wrong with the canvas translation or with save and restore? I don't know, why it was working fine on Emulator and not on Device.